# Delphi XE4 iOS and TMemo hidden / cut-off text

Tags: ios, delphi

I have an a few issues with the TMemo in iOS / firemonkey, One issue it seems some text is hidden (bottom paragraph) until user start drag/scroll. (However, the visible area in TMemo could hold nearly all the text if it wanted. But it first draws when user issues scroll.)

I have tried call **SetFocus** to trigger the same effect like drag/scroll, but no luck.

Underneath are some screenshots:

First how it looks like when broken (see bottom):

[image]

Then how it looks like when the memo redraws itself after a tiny drag:

[image]

As can be seen, the memo has not actually been scrolled/dragged in image two, but the initiation of of the operation was enough to make the memo draw its text correctly.

I can add that it always happens if the memoy has shown other text string earlier. (I suspect it may be some weird internal formatting/draw issue.)

Comment: What happens if you call Memo.Update() ?

Comment: @whosrdaddy There is no such method. I have tried calling **Repaint**

Comment: Try Memo.Lines.BeginUpdate, Memo.Lines.EndUpdate.

Comment: hm, try that hack: when drag/scroll starts, remove hidden text, when it stops, paste removed text again. I think this is bug of FireMonkey. If you use XE3, see changelog of XE4 or updates patch for XE3, may be it fixed.

Comment: I am using XE4, but I will continue looking into different "hacks" and report back if any of the suggested hacks work :)

Comment: @Tom I had similar problem with Memo in XE4, but FMX desktop application. After setting text to the Memo I added following lines:

`Memo1.NeedStyleLookup;`
`Memo1.ApplyStyleLookup;`

I hope it works for you also.

Comment: @slotomo no luck with that. I make the calls after seting the text :(